# SendInput not work consecutively

Tags: windows, winapi, mouseevent

I've written a c++ snippet to simulate mouse click as following.

```
INPUT mouseData[2];
ZeroMemory(mouseData, sizeof(mouseData));

mouseData[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
mouseData[0].mi.dx = xx;
mouseData[0].mi.dy = yy;
mouseData[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
mouseData[0].mi.mouseData = 0;
mouseData[0].mi.time = 0;

mouseData[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
mouseData[1].mi.dx = 10;
mouseData[1].mi.dy = 10;
mouseData[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
mouseData[1].mi.mouseData = 0;
mouseData[1].mi.time = 0;

SendInput(1, &mouseData[0], sizeof(INPUT));
Sleep(30);
SendInput(1, &mouseData[1], sizeof(INPUT));
```

But it doesn't work well.
Former SendInput works, but latter SendInput doesn't work.
Why?

Another:  I've tried SendInput as following

1. call SendInput for mouse click
2. Click the mouse manually on any position of screen.
3. call SendInput

Above works well.
But without 2, it doesn't work. why?

Comment: This is going to be *very* confusing to any program that gets the mouse notifications.  Don't do it all at the same time, first you move, then down, then up.

Comment: You put these events in an array so that they can be processed atomically. Don't send them one at a time. One call to SendInput with all the events. And you need one event for each distinct action. Read the documentation.

Comment: You are setting wrong flags. Are you sure Left down and Left up flags can be sent in single input?

Answer (score 2):

MSDN is not super helpful in [its description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273(v=vs.85).aspx) of valid flags

> The bits in this member can be any reasonable combination of the following values.

I personally would not say that it is reasonable to use both the down and up flags in the same input command. For maximum compatibility with all applications, perform the action like a normal user would: move, button down and finally button up.

I would recommend that you create a helper function that performs these three input steps if you are going to do a lot of mouse manipulation.